# Making a Textbox invisible or read only

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, css

```
<html>
<body>
  <form action="MyInserts.php" method="GET">
    <a href="http://localhost/login.htm" target="_blank">CLICK HERE TO LOGIN</a>
    <br>
    <p><u>Create Acct</u></p>
    <br>
    firstname: <input type="text" name="firstbox"><br>
    lastname:  <input type="text" name="lastbox"><br>
    id number:  <input type="text" name="idbox"><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Create">
  </form>
</html>
```

Comment: `<input disabled="disabled">` or `<input type="hidden">` or `<input readonly="readonly">`

Comment: do u wish to get the data at POST event?

Comment: Seeing the answers, you should consider that your question is not precise enough...

Comment: how do i edit it in the code please?

Comment: Which input do you want to be readonly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Readonly :

```
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="firstbox" readonly>
```

Invisible

```
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="firstbox" style="display: none">
```

Comment: display: none is not invisible :)

Answer (score 6):

Readonly:

```
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="firstbox" readonly="readonly">
```

Disable:

```
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="firstbox" disabled="disabled">
```

Invisible:

```
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="firstbox" type="hidden">
```

**UPDATE**

> READONLY and DISABLED both remove the functionality of the input
>   field, but to different degrees. READONLY locks the field: the user
>   cannot change the value. DISABLED does the same thing but takes it
>   further: the user cannot use the field in any way, not to highlight
>   the text for copying, not to select the checkbox, not to submit the
>   form. In fact, a disabled field is not even sent if the form is
>   submitted.

Comment: missing `type="hidden"`

Comment: @kleinfreund readonly is when...you can read only and disabled is when it is...disabled

Answer (score 1):

Note: to use jQuery, you must include it by adding something like:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

To hide it with jQuery:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function() {
        $('input[type="text"]').first().hide();
    });
</script>
```

To disable it, substitute this into above:

```
$(function() {
    $('input[type="text"]').first().prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Comment: how do i edit it in the code please?

Answer (score 1):

Use readonly in that attribute of textbox tag,

```
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="firstbox" readonly>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `readonly="readonly"`

```
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="firstbox" readonly="readonly">
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mnrjr/)**

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS:

```
input[name=firstbox]
{
   display: none;
}
```

or change html:

```
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="firstbox" readonly>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `disabled="disabled"`  example

```
<input type="text" name="firstbox" disabled="disabled" />
```

or `readonly="readonly"`

```
<input type="text" name="firstbox" readonly="readonly" />
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/enve/SyDpX/

Answer (score 0):

CSS attributes:

- [visibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/visibility)
- [display](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/display)

HTML attributes:

- [readonly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/textbox#a-readonly)
- [disabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/textbox#a-disabled)

Answer (score 0):

use this to disable textbox:

```
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="firstbox" disabled>
```